# Data processing before save in django model

Tags: python, django

I want to make an automated site in Django model, As an automated if user input unit and quantity it is not good to input also total, I think you understand what I mean it would be.
my models looks like this
model.py:

```py
    unit_price = models.FloatField(max_length=24)
    quantity = models.FloatField(max_length=24)
    total_price = models.FloatField(max_length=24)
```

view.py:

```py
    posted = dataForm(request.POST)
    if posted.is_valid():
        posted.save()
```

what I want is that user inputs `quantity` and `unit_price` only and

```
total_price = quantity * unit_price
```

So how can I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

A `ModelForm` wraps an `.instance` that will be saved, you thus can manipulate the `.instance` object:

```
posted = dataForm(request.POST)
if posted.is_valid():
    item = posted.instance
    item.total_price = item.quantity * item.unit_price
    posted.save()
```

That being said, if the `total_price` is always the `quantity` times toe `unit_price`, there is no need to save that in the model, you can calculate that when you need it, or use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to calculate that at the database side.